# Python CSV writer missing row of data

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm experiencing a problem when I dump json data into a CSV file. There is typically a block of json data that is missing from my the CSV file, but can be seen if I print the json in the console or to a file.

Essentially I am calling a service twice and receiving back two json responses that I parse and dump into a CSV file. The service can only be called for 7 day increments (unix time), so I have implemented logic to call the service for this increment over a period of time.

I'm using the python vanilla `json` and `csv` libraries.

First the CSV is created with headers:

```
with open ('history_' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")+'.csv', 'wb') as outcsv:
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv)
    writer.writerow(["Column1","Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5",
              "Column6"])
```

Then, I have a counter that calls the service twice, fifty times (following the open of the CSV file):

```
while y<50:
    jsoResponseOne = getJsonOne(7)
    jsonResponseTwo = getJsonTwo(7)
```

Example json response:

```
{"Value": 
  [
    {"ExampleName": "Test", 
     "ExampleNameTwo": "Test2", 
     "ExampleDate": "1436103790", 
     "ExampleCode": 00000001, 
     "ExampleofExample": "abcd", 
     "AnotherExample": "hello"},
     {"ExampleName": "Test2", 
     "ExampleNameTwo": "Test3", 
     "ExampleDate": "1436103790", 
     "ExampleCode": 00000011, 
     "ExampleofExample": "abcd", 
     "AnotherExample": "hello2"},
  ]
}
```

The CSV output columns would look like:

```
ExampleName   ExampleNameTwo   ExampleDate   ExampleCode  ExampleofExample   AnotherExample
```

Finally, the CSV is written as follows:

```
for item in jsonResponseOne['Value']:
                row = []
                row.append(str(item['ExampleName'].encode('utf-8')))
                if item.get("ExampleNameTwo"):
                    row.append(str(item["ExampleNameTwo"]))
                else:
                    row.append("None")
                row.append(str(item['ExampleDate']))
                row.append(str(item['ExampleCode'].encode('utf-8')))
                row.append(str(item['ExampleofExample'].encode('utf-8')))
                row.append(str(item['AnotherExample'].encode('utf-8')))
                writer.writerow(row)
for item in jsonResponseTwo['Value']:
                anotherRow= []
                anotherRow.append(str(item['ExampleName'].encode('utf-8')))
                if item.get("ExampleNameTwo"):
                    anotherRow.append(str(item["ExampleNameTwo"]))
                else:
                    anotherRow.append("None")
                anotherRow.append(str(item['ExampleDate']))
                anotherRow.append(str(item['ExampleCode'].encode('utf-8')))
                anotherRow.append(str(item['ExampleofExample'].encode('utf-8')))
                anotherRow.append(str(item['AnotherExample'].encode('utf-8')))
                writer.writerow(anotherRow)
```

Why could my CSV output be missing an entire row of data (a block of data from the JSON response)?

Comment: Show us an example of the json data and what is missing as well.

Comment: You didn't say what was missing.

Comment: Hi Anand. The CSV is missing an entire row of data. Each row is a block of json code. A response may have many blocks of json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

The Python script had an indentation issue in the one of the while loops, causing some data to be skipped over and not written to the CSV file.